# How do I get the pivot of a RotateDrawable programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I want to use a series of `RotateDrawable` objects to animate a compound pendulum (so the pivot point of a second `RotateDrawable` must be "attached" to a point on a first `RotateDrawable`).  This means I need to calculate where a point in the drawable is after a rotation has taken place.  There don't seem to be methods for getting or setting the pivot of a `RotateDrawable`; short of retrieving them directly from XML when the thing is inflated I can't think of a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the pivot from XML during inflation can be done in a manner similar to:

```
//r is a Resources object containing the layout
//id is an integer from R.drawable
XmlPullParser parser = r.getXml(id);
AttributeSet attrs = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
float pivotX = attrs.getAttributeFloatValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "pivotX", 0.5f);
float pivotY = attrs.getAttributeFloatValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "pivotY", 0.5f);

//d is a RotateDrawable
d.inflate(r, parser, attrs);
```

The attribute SHOULD be between zero and one (if present) and 0.5f is the default value set by Android if the attribute is absent.

http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#rotate

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

I've realized it's also important to get `android:fromDegrees` and `android:toDegrees` as if, like me, you're using `onLevelChanged(int)` to get the quantity of rotation, you need to know how much rotation you are actually getting.  The same method works for these attributes.  The defaults are 0.0f and 360.0f (in degrees).  Level is between 0 and 10,000, with 0 corresponding to `fromDegrees` and 10,000 corresponding to `toDegrees`.

Comment: I've decided to use a standard `Drawable` displaying a `Bitmap` on a `Canvas` anyway, as the `Matrix` class makes it easier to program translations (and the dependent elements of a compound pendulum would have to translate).